# Config Transform does not work?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have this config in my **Web.config** file:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="LocalConnString" connectionString="metadata=res://*/;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\NCU.Joberwocky.Db.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

This in my **Web.Release.config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="LocalConnString" connectionString="metadata=res://*/;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=192.168.10.3;Initial Catalog=AeorionJobs;User Id=aeorionjobs;Password=aejobs3695;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;"
       xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

When I switch the build to release, it still uses the config from **Web.config**. Any idea what the problem is?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am also struggling with configuration transforms. Actually I am trying to have a different configuration on my environment than the common one uploaded in code control.

I have been also trying the same thing as you are doing and I would say those transforms are only applied on the deployment packages that you can build.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So I cannot just set the build and then click run and it chooses the correct one? I need to deploy it?

Comment: That's correct, it will do the transformation only when building the deployment package.

Comment: I was also reading some articles on how to get the deployment package build work with app.config (http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2010/05/applying-xdt-magic-to-appconfig.html this is one of them) and based on that there might be some way to include the transformation on the build script, but I didn't try it